# Refactoring variables in different scopes

Tags: javascript

```
$(function () {
    var wrapper = $('.table-wrapper');
    var table = $('.multiples-table');
    var filter = $('.filter');

    //use these variables in calculations

    $('#filter').keyup(function () {
        var wrapper = $('.table-wrapper');
        var table = $('.multiples-table');
        var filter = $('.filter');

        //use the same variables in different calculations
    });
});
```

How can I refactor these variables so I only have to declare them once? Thank you.

Comment: Move them out of the function into the global scope. However, that's generally a bad idea because they can be altered by other code there. What you're doing is fine, and not worth optimizing away.

Comment: simply don't declare variables by the same name in the inner context.

Comment: `use these variables in calculations` but u know, that these variables contain arraylike structures referencing DOM-nodes, and not some (numeric) values to do calculations with !? you have to fetch the values of these nodes prior to do calculations and this step can't be cached/moved out of the actual function you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So those variables are already specific to your top most function's content. So unless you change them somewhere in that function, you can simply use them directly in your keyup function:

```
$(function () {
    var wrapper = $('.table-wrapper');
    var table = $('.multiples-table');
    var filter = $('.filter');

    //use these variables in calculations

    $('#filter').keyup(function () {
        // just use wrapper, table and filter here, as is. No need to re-declare them

        //use the same variables in different calculations
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: just to be precise: the problem is not the re-definition, the problem is the __declaration__ *(of new variables by the same names)*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$(function () {
    var wrapper = $('.table-wrapper');
    var table = $('.multiples-table');
    var filter = $('.filter');

    //use these variables in calculations

    $('#filter').keyup(function () {
        let wrapper = $('.table-wrapper');
        let table = $('.multiples-table');
        let filter = $('.filter');

        //use the same variables in different calculations
    });
});
```